# Weird File Attributes in Excel Save Dialog

Tags: microsoft-excel, metadata, file-attributes

I vertically re-sized my excel `Save As` dialog today and found a bunch of strange file attributes that I've never seen in the dialog before.  They only appear when the dialog is resized small enough that they appear, or when you click the browse folders button to make the folders disappear (which I never do).

Do these remain attached to the file between copies between servers and file system types?   Apparently they're specific to office documents as notepad doesn't have any of these.   Also what are they called?

[image: Strange file attributes]

Comment: It's call [Metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) - Data about the data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's just metadata for the file. It is just fields that can store extra information about a file. Right click on the file and then select properties and you will see the list of tags under the details tab.

The metadata will stick when you copy it to another computer.

Comment: You've avoided the hard questions.. Will it stick if he copies it to a different computer? What if that computer is running Linux, or OSX, does it stick?

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice Calc menu:File -> Properties -> Dialog -- contains the same stuff.

Excel has it too, may be slightly different place though.

It is saved inside the file.